# Regular Expression to match Global currency values

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match all of the following formats:

```
$ 1.234,56
R$ 1.234,56
1.234,56 $
1.234,56 Kč
kr. 1.234,56
€1.234,56
HK$ 1,234.56
1.234,56 Ft
₹ 1,234.56
₪ 1.234,56
¥ 1,234.56
₩ 1,234.56
RM 1,234.56
$ 1,234.56
kr 1,234.56
₱ 1,234.56
1.234,56 zł
1.234,56 p.
$1,234.56
R 1,234.56
1.234,56 kr
fr. 1.234,56
元 1,234.56
1,234.56 ฿
1,234.56 ₺
£1,234.56
$1,234.56
1.234,56 ₫
$0
$0.00
$ 0,00
$ 0.00
0.00
0,00
1234.00
1234,00
(1,234.00)
$(1,234.00)
($1,234.00)
-$1,234.00
-1234.00
$-1,234.00
234.00 CR
234.00 DR
234.00 WD
234.00 W/D
```

CR and DR should be able to be upper, mixed, and lowercase like this:
CR, Cr, cR, cr

WD and W/D should be able to be upper and lowercase only like this:
WD, wd, W/D, w/d

It must exclude standalone numbers that do not conform to a currency format (i.e. 4, 45, 456, 4567, and so on). If a number does not contain a currency symbol, either before or after (ref the formats I provided) it must contain proper currency formatting via decimal and/or comma separation (i.e. 234.00, 234,00, 1234.00 1234,00 and so on).

Also, any dollar amount must be able to be used as long as it conforms to proper formatting. The examples I've provided are just that, examples.

I've gotten pretty close but can't seem to get it right.

Here's what I have so far:

```
^(?:[$€£₹¥฿₽₺₴₸₣₱₩₮₡₢₣₲₳₵₪₺﷼]|(?:[A-Z]{2,3}\\s?\\.?\\s?))?\\s?\\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\\d{3})*(?:[.,]\\d{2})?\\s?(?:[$€£₹¥฿₽₺₴₸₣₱₩₮₡₢₣₲₳₵₪₺﷼]|(?:[A-Z]{2,3}\\s?\\.?\\s?))?$
```

This is being used for finding currency amounts within transactions on bank statements from all over the world.

Thanks in advance to all the regex experts!

Comment: What about `1,234 USD` et al.?

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/no5CDH/1

Comment: @sln That doesn't look very DRY.

Comment: sln, I appreciate your efforts but one of the main conditions has to be to accept any dollar amount. While you have created something that matches exactly what my examples are, you cannot change the dollar amount to $1,234,567.89 and get a match.

Comment: InSync, 1,234 USD does not appear on bank statements AKAIK. The global way currency amount appear on bank statements are the formats I've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/y4VQEQ/4)

It took a lot of nested groups `((...))` and alternation `|` to meet the criterias and match specific strings from the OP list.

```js
/^(([$-]){1,2}|([$€£]\s?)|([₹₪¥₩₱R元]|R\$|kr\.?|HK\$|RM?|fr\.)\s) 
((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?))$
|
^(-?(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?))
\s(Kč|Ft|zł|p\.|kr|[Cc][Rr]|[Dd][Rr]|W\/?D|w\/?d|[$฿₺₫])$
|
^(([$-]){1,2}\(|\(([$-]){1,2}|\$\(-|-\(\$|\()
(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)\)$
|
^-?\d{1,4}([,.]\d{3})*[,.]\d{2}$
|
^(\$\s|-\$|\$-)\d{1,3}$
/gm
```

## Example

## ```js
const regexp = /^(([$-]){1,2}|([$€£]\s?)|([₹₪¥₩₱R元]|R\$|kr\.?|HK\$|RM?|fr\.)\s)((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?))$|^(-?(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?))\s(Kč|Ft|zł|p\.|kr|[Cc][Rr]|[Dd][Rr]|W\/?D|w\/?d|[$฿₺₫])$|^(([$-]){1,2}\(|\(([$-]){1,2}|\$\(-|-\(\$|\()(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)\)$|^-?\d{1,4}([,.]\d{3})*[,.]\d{2}$|^(\$\s|-\$|\$-)\d{1,3}$/gm;

const string = `$1,234.56
£1,234.56
$1.234,56
€1.234,56
$ 1,234.56
$ 1.234,56
R 1,234.56
₹ 1,234.56
₹ 1,234.56
₹ 1,234.56
¥ 1,234.56
₩ 1,234.56
元 1,234.56
R$ 1.234,56
RM 1,234.56
kr 1,234.56
kr. 1.234,56
fr. 1.234,56
HK$ 1,234.56
1.234,56 $
1,234.56 ฿
1,234.56 ₺
1.234,56 ₫
1.234,56 Ft
1.234,56 kr
1.234,56 p.
1.234,56 Kč
1.234,56 zł
$0
$0.00
$ 0,00
$ 0.00
0.00
0,00
$12,345,678.90
$12.345.678,90
1,234,567,890.00 $
12.34
12,34
1,234.56
12.345.67
12,345,67
1,234 $
1,234.45 $
1.234 $
1.234,45 $
$123
$1.234
$1,234
1234.56
1234,56
(1,234.56)
$(1,234.56)
($1,234.56)
-$1,234.56
-1234.56
$-1,234.56
123.45 CR
123.45 DR
123.45 WD
123.45 W/D
The proceeding lines do not match
1
123.456
123,456
123.0
$12.3
.12
$12,3
$1223456
$.123
$1,0000
$1234
`;

const matches = string.match(regexp);

console.log(`${matches.length} matches in 73 lines.`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(matches));
console.log(`The last match is: ${matches[matches.length-1]}`);
```

| #### Sub-pattern | #### Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` / ``` | Start of regular expression |
| ``` ^(([$-]){1,2}|([$€£]\s?)|([₹₪¥₩₱R元]|R$|kr.?|HK$|RM?|fr.)\s) ``` | Start of line - match 1 or 2 literal `$` and/or `-` **or** either a literal `$`, `€`, or `£` followed by 0 or 1 space **or** a literal `₹`, `₪`, `¥`, `₩`, `₱`, `R`, or `元` followed by a space **or** literal `kr` and 0 or 1 `.` followed by a space **or** a literal `HK$` followed by a space **or** a literal `fr.` followed by a space... |
| ``` ((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})(.\d{2})?)|(\d{1,3}(.\d{3})(,\d{2})?))$ ``` | ...then match 1 to 3 digits followed by 0 or more groups of a literal `,` and 3 digits followed by 0 or 1 group of a literal `.` and 2 digits **or** match 1 to 3 digits followed by 0 or more groups of a literal `.` and 3 digits followed by 0 or 1 group of a literal `,` and 2 digits - end of line |
| ``` | ``` | **OR** |
| ``` ^(-?(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})(.\d{2})?)|(\d{1,3}(.\d{3})(,\d{2})?)) ``` | Start of line - match 0 or 1 literal `-` then refer to 2nd row 2nd cell... |
| ``` \s(Kč|Ft|zł|p.|kr|[Cc][Rr]|[Dd][Rr]|W/?D|w/?d|[$฿₺₫])$ ``` | ...then match 1 space followed by either a literal `Kč`, **or** `Ft`, **or** `zł`, **or** `p.`, **or** `kr`, **or** `C/c` and `R/r`, `D/d` and `R/r`, **or** `W` followed by 0 or more `/` and 1 `D`, **or** `w` followed by 0 or more `/` and 1 `d`, **or** either a literal `$`, `฿`, `₺`, or `₫` - end of line |
| ``` | ``` | **OR** |
| ``` ^(([$-]){1,2}(|(([$-]){1,2}|$(-|-($|() ``` | Start of line - match 1 or 2 literal `$` and/or `-` followed by a literal `(` **or** a literal `(` followed by 1 or 2 literal `$` and/or `-` **or** a literal `$(-` **or** a literal `$(-` **or** a literal `(`... |
| ``` (\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(.\d{2})?))$ ``` | ...then match 1 to 3 digits followed by 0 or more groups of a literal `,` and 3 digits followed by 0 or 1 group of a literal `.` and 2 digits followed by a literal `)` - end of line |
| ``` | ``` | **OR** |
| ``` ^-?\d{1,4}([,.]\d{3})*[,.]\d{2}$ ``` | Start of line - match 0 or 1 literal `-` followed by 1 to 4 digits followed by 0 or more groups of either a literal `.` or `,` and 3 digits followed by either a literal `.` or `,` and 2 digits - end of line |
| ``` | ``` | **OR** |
| ``` ^($\s|-$|$-)\d{1,3}$ ``` | Start of line - match a literal `$` and 1 space **or** a literal `-$` **or** a literal `$-` followed by 1 to 3 digits - end of line |
| ``` /gm ``` | End of regular expression - `g`lobal flag: continue to find matches after the first match / `m`ultiline flag: `^` = start of a line `$` = end of line |

Comment: This is pretty close but you're not matching strings like 12.34 12,34, 12.345.67, 12,345.67, 1,234 $, 1,234.45 $ 1.234 $, or 1,234.45 $. Remember that I need all of the formats I described in the original post to match, while excluding only standalone numbers that do not contain decimals or commas such as 4, 45, 456, 4567, and so on. This is the closes so far, so well done.

Comment: @kittonian Ok, please review update.

Comment: That's amazing and super close to perfect!

All examples below need to match with all the formats as well.

It's not matching on standalone numbers such as
234.00
234,00
1234.00
1234,00 and so on

I missed a couple of formats (apologies) such as
(1,234.00)
$(1,234.00)
($1,234.00)
-$1,234.00
-1234.00
$-1,234.00

and finally the credit/debit designations such as
234.00 CR
234.00 DR
234.00 WD
234.00 W/D
CR and DR should be able to be upper, mixed, and lowercase (CR, Cr, cR, or cr)
WD and W/D should be able to be upper and lowercase only (WD, wd, W/D, w/d)

Comment: My apologies. I was looking at the wrong answer on regex101. Everything I commented stands, except that you have in fact match 234.00 and 234,00 properly. Everything else still needs to be matched but I wanted to let you know when I realized. Thanks!

Comment: Add the criteria mentioned in previous comments to your question, I'm kind of losing track of all of the changes.

Comment: Done. Should've done that initially instead of writing it in a comment.

Comment: @kittonian I updated the [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/y4VQEQ/3) example, I'll update the answer after work, good luck .

Comment: You're amazing. That's incredible and works perfectly. Just tested it and had the accountant test it too. Perfection. Thank you so much!

Comment: @kittonian I'm glad it worked. While updating the rest of the answer, I found a minor discrepancy: a sub-pattern was repeated but it is on an alternation so the result isn't affected. The link to [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/y4VQEQ/4) has been updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Subpattern definitions
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<number>                         # Match a nicely formatted number
    (?=\d+[.,]|0\D)                  # that has at least one dot or comma, or is '0',
    \d{1,3}                          # starts with 1 to 3 digits,
    (?=(?<separator>[.,]))?          # an optional separator which we capture,
    (?:\k<separator>\d{3})*          # then 0+ 3-digit groups separated by it
    (?:(?!\k<separator>)[.,]\d{2})?  # and ends with optional decimal places.
  )

  (?<currency>
    # Unicode property for currency signs
    \p{Sc}
  |
    # Single-char symbols not included in the property above
    [元圆圓] # etc.
  |
    # Multiple-char currencies need to be input manually
    (?:HK|R)?\$|[kf]r(?:\s*\.)?|RM?|Ft|zł|Kč|p\.

    # Use \p{L}{1,3}(?:\s*\.)? when in despair
  )
)

# Real matching pattern
^                                    # Match at the start of string
(?:                                  # either
  \g<currency>\s*\g<number>          # a currency-number pair
|                                    # or
  \g<number>(?:\s*\g<currency>)?     # a number-currency pair or a number
)                                    # right before
$                                    # the end of string.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lM9mXB/4).

Comment: Appreciated, but unfortunately that doesn't work. I need a single string, as this will be going into Swift code and properly escaped, once I've tested that it works. It must match any dollar amount in the formats I provided and NOT match standalone numbers that are not properly formatted with either a decimal or comma. This means that 4, 45, 456, 4567 and so on should NOT match because they do not contain decimals or commas. But should match $1,234,567.78 or any other dollar amount.

Comment: @kittonian Including `$0` and `$1234`?

Comment: Including everything I described in my original post. $0 yes, $1234 no because it would need to be $1,234 or $1.234 but $12 or $123 should match. Any dollar amount in the formats I provided. This expression has to match any format of a transaction in a bank statement, whether it be in US dollars or another global currency.

Comment: @kittonian Fixed. Check to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you. zer00ne got super close to perfect and I just commented on his answer with the couple things that were not working, as well as few other formats I was just made aware of. Check out my latest comment on his answer.